# Erasure of type parameters

Tags: java, generics

I have a class like below:

```
public class MyList<E> {
    private List<E> list;
    public void setList(List<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public List<E> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

I read that after type erasure all occurrence of the type parameter `E` is replaced by `Object`. So after type erasure the class will become:

```
public class MyList {
    private List<Object> list;
    public void setList(List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public List<Object> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

`List<String>` is not assignable to `List<Object>`. But we can pass `List<String>` to the setter method like following:

```
MyList<String> ml = new MyList<String>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ml.setList(list);
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: The point of type erasure is that **generics** are erased - `List list`.

Comment: Read the docs fully. They don't say it is replaced with `Object`.[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) says: *Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object* ***if the type parameters are unbounded.*** So, the type is replaced with `Object` if *and only if* no type has been specified (Like `List list` or `List<?> list`

Answer (score 2):

The type is erased after compilation but before that the compiler checks if all the the types are consistent so you cannot give a `List<Object>` where a `List<String>` is expected.

Here is an excerpt from [Baeldung's article](http://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure) about type erasure.

> The compiler ensures type safety of our code and prevents runtime
>   errors.